# Getting wrong R.drawable reference Ids when using ant build

Tags: android, ant

After using ant build, I get some drawable ids mixed up when I am trying to assign them problematically(not in the xml).

I have an array that is holding some drawable ids:

```
int[]ids={R.drawable.pic1,R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3,R.drawable.pic4};
```

And when I try to assign them to an imageview a different drawable is displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(ids[0]);
}
```

It doesn't happen when I set the drawable in the xml, this works :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/pic1" />
```

Comment: can you please show code where you are assign them to an imageview .

Comment: It works when I run it in eclipse, so probably i'm doing it right in the code, but what might be causing it when using ant build?

Comment: Did you intend to have `R.drawawble.pic1` listed twice in that array?

Comment: I have 10 drawables, the names are all different.
I will edit my question.

Comment: Are you always explicitly loading the `[0]` element of the array, or is something else driving which one is used?

Comment: for the question yes, just to display the problem that I am having.
I iterate within the array and assign a different id dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing Eclipse and running `ant clean` followed by `ant` from the command line. If that works, the most likely problem is that your ant script is building to the same directories as Eclipse, and if Eclipse is running while doing the ant build, it may detect changed files and run its own builds at the same time. This can cause some inconsistent results based on timing of the builds.

In general, be sure that your ant scripts build to different directories from those that Eclipse uses. This includes the "gen" directory - use a separate one for ant.

Comment: Will disabling auto build in eclipse or closing the project might help too?

Comment: Yep - that would be good to try as well and should avoid eclipse running its build.

Answer (score 0):

#### Trying getting drawable through resources :

```
 int[]ids={ getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2)};
```

If getting error in getResources() then try using

```
 int[]ids={ YourActivityName.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1), YourActivityName.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2)};
```

#### try these method too ::

#### Remove int [] id and try to fetch it directly::

```
  iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

Comment: I have tried everything, even getting the 'id' by the name of the resource, and it still mixes everything up.

Comment: That won't work; getDrawable returns a Drawable, not an int... The way he's using setBackgroundResource should work...

Comment: @user1940676 try using the another method which i edited few seconds back. Do Vote up if it helps

Comment: I can't vote up or down, but thank you for trying to help. The solution was in the second answer.